# Javascript - Issue with mouse events and floating element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mouseover, mouseout

I've got a tricky problem with a script I'm writing using jQuery.

I have a table which will have a toolbar appear on any row if hovered over (except the heading row).  This is working great, and this is the code for it:

```
$cont.delegate('tr:not(:eq(0))','mouseover mouseout', function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    var pos = $this.position();
    if(e.type == 'mouseout') {
        $actionToolbar.hide();
    } else {
        $actionToolbar.css({
            'top'  : pos.top  + $this.height()/2 - $actionToolbar.height()/2,
            'left' : pos.left + $this.width()    - $actionToolbar.width()
        }).show();
    }
});
```

The problem arises when I hover over the action toolbar. The row's `mouseout` event fires, and the toolbar hides (then enters an infinite loop of showing/hiding).  This is because the toolbar is absolutely positioned and not a child of the row.

Here's the deal:

- I **do not** want it to be a child of the row, because that means I'd have to remove and append to the DOM for every mouse event -- and this is not as efficient as simply updating the element's CSS.
- I would also like to **avoid timers** to solve this if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having little patience, I've gone and found my own answer:

I've removed the `mouseout` event listener and moved to using jQuery's `data()` method to keep track of the previously hovered row.  Then, I add a `mouseleave` event listener to the container.

It works perfectly:

```
$cont.delegate('tr:not(:eq(0))', 'mouseover', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $($cont.data('COLStorage.row')).removeClass(opts.hoverClass);
    $this.addClass(opts.hoverClass);
    var pos = $this.position();
    $actionToolbar.css({
        'top': pos.top + $this.height() / 2 - $actionToolbar.height() / 2,
        'left': pos.left + $this.width() - $actionToolbar.width()
    }).show();
    $cont.data('COLStorage.row', $this);
}).mouseleave(function(e) {
    $actionToolbar.fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try mouseenter and mouseleave instead of mouseover and mouseout.

Comment: `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` do not work with event delegation. It wouldn't solve the problem anyway, as the toolbar is not a child element of the row.

Answer (score 0):

Put a marker css selector on your action toolbar and check for it using jquery. Then don't apply if your event's target has that marker selector.